# Speakers Plugged into Sound Card Appear as Headphones?

Tags: sound, headphones, soundcard, speakers

I have a pair of speakers plugged into an Asus Xonar DSX sound card currently. When I go into the audio settings they are treated as headphones and the sound that comes out of them is noticeably "headphone-y" as in very muffled and like it's designed to be coming out right in your ears requiring me to turn them up all the way to get a decent volume.

When I enter into Counter-Strike: Global Offensive as well the only audio option I have is headphones, there is no 2 speakers option which is strange. Is this because I am using a sound card? Will I need to switch them to the onboard audio jack everytime I switch from Windows to Ubuntu?

Any help would be a appreciated thanks!

Comment: what profile options are available in sound card preferences?

Comment: Only Analog Stereo Output.